# How to change font color offsetbox TextArea

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, colors

```
from matplotlib.offsetbox import TextArea
rc('font',**{'family': 'Courier New, monospace', 'size' : 26})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
txt = TextArea("Hello World!")
text = AnnotationBbox(txt, (0, 0, 0))
ax.add_artist(text)
```

Is there any way to change the colour of this text ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

The [`Textarea`](https://matplotlib.org/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.TextArea) has an argument `textprops` which can be used to set the color of the text.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import TextArea, AnnotationBbox

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
txt = TextArea("Hello World!", textprops=dict(color="crimson"))
text = AnnotationBbox(txt, (0.5, 0.5))
ax.add_artist(text)

plt.show()
```

[image]